# Weird flicker before CSS transform animation starts

Tags: css, animation

Why do I get a quick flash of my square at full size before the animation starts? : http://jsfiddle.net/q6dwhrca/

I've been going through multiple threads on SO, and the classic solution :

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

...simply doesn't work for me.

I've tried many different things (not in the JSFiddle); not using the `display` property (instead using a `from {height:0px;} to {height:100px;}` animation), I've tried simply having a `transform:scale(0);` applied on my square before the animation is triggered, or having the `backface-visibility` property (and the perspective property and more) on parents/children of my square etc... Nothing works.

My only theory is that this is due to the actual matrix3d animation, which was created on Bounce.js.

The thing that weirds me out, is that it all seems to start at 0, as expected.

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I am sorry but when I play with this in your fiddle I don't  see any strange behavior

Comment: I think it's because you made that effect on the animation. If you remove the frames betwen `0%` and `11.61%` the animation change yes, but you don't get the flash of the start.

Comment: @Franco No need to apologize :) What browser are you using? I'm seeing this behavior in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox. Perhaps if you increase the animation's ms (presently at 2000) you'll have time to see it.

Comment: @Gonzalo Interesting. I really can't tell what causes this between the 0% - 11.61% frames. I'll have to investigate.

Comment: You can use simplier animations, like scale animation and change the linear aceleration to other that give you the effect you are searching

Comment: @Gonzalo Yes I've tried that, but I really couldn't get a cubic-bezier animation to look as good and smooth as the Bounce.js one. It's a shame really, as I feel so close to the solution.